# How do I split this datestamp in Google Sheets

Tags: csv, google-sheets, datestamp

I have a datestamp in this format on C6:

```
21/05/2021 10:41:35 PM
```

How can I split this into date and time so that I have date in D6 and time in E6?

I want to do this because I have browsing history I want to import to calendar.

I found several answers to this question with various answers but none of them worked for me.

Comment: The problem is whether your data is a string or a date. Post a spreadsheet with it and you'll get an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SPLIT(C6, " ")` to split contents of the cell.
This splits the time and AM/PM too, but you can join it in another cell using `JOIN(" ", E6:F6)`

Answer (score 1):

date in Google Sheets is always an integer, and time is a fractional number, so you can divide the date and time very easily

[image]

Comment: I wish I understood what that meant.. :D I'm just a beginner trying to turn this long date into 2 columns with the date and time. I've tried this and it returns a #VALUE! error message. Any further suggestions?

Comment: if the value is a date, not a string, use =split(C6," ")

Answer (score 1):

**Since your data comes from an imported `.csv` file, it could be formatted as text.**
If that is the case, try the following formula

```
=SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(.*\/\d+) ","$1@"),"@")
```

[image]

You can then format the results to your liking.

*(As always, do adjust ranges and locale as needed)*

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple option that you can use as long as each datestamp is exactly the same:

Use the `LEFT()` and `RIGHT()` functions.  (These also work in Excel)

For the date, use `LEFT(DATESTAMP_CELL,10)`.  This will return the first 10 characters from the cell, which in this case are the date "21/05/2021".

For the time, use `RIGHT(DATESTAMP_CELL,11)`.  This will return the last 11 characters from the cell, which in this case are the time "10:41:35 PM".

This should be the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but it returned a #NAME? error. Do you have any other suggestions of what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: In those formulas, the "DATESTAMP_CELL" should be a reference to the cell with the datestamp in it.  In this case, if the datestamp is in A1, the formula should be "=LEFT(A1,10)" and "=RIGHT(A1,11)"